# Shadow effect in Recyclerview items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-elevation

I want to achieve a design with a linear layout and few widgets along with shadow effect such as elevation, but I'm unable to get the shadows right.

I tried to adding elevation no to the linear layout, but it doesn't show any effect in the design.

I tried cardview also, but I'm not getting the desired shadow effect.

My Recylerview Item XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_rounded_corner_black"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
          android:layout_width="13dp"
          android:layout_height="13dp"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:visibility="gone"
          app:civ_border_width="1dp"/>

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_time"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_book"
          android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          tools:text="12 PM"/>

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_book"
          android:text="2.1 mi."
          android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey"
          android:textSize="14sp"/>

      </RelativeLayout>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_workout_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_heavy"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black_1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="HIIT Workout"/>


      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_type_of_booking"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_book"
        android:text="One-Time Booking"
        android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

My RecyclerView item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:clipToPadding="false">


  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#F3f3f3"
      android:clipToPadding="false">

        <com.marcohc.robotocalendar.RobotoCalendarView
          android:id="@+id/robotoCalendarView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:elevation="10dp"
          android:visibility="visible"
          app:mcv_calendarMode="month"
          app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/CalendarDateTextAppearance"
          app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/CalendarHeaderTextAppearance"
          app:mcv_leftArrow="@drawable/mcv_action_previous"
          app:mcv_monthLabels="@null"
          app:mcv_rightArrow="@drawable/mcv_action_next"
          app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/color_red"
          app:mcv_selectionMode="single"
          app:mcv_showOtherDates="out_of_range"
          app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalendarWeekTextAppearance"/>

      <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msvw"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/rv_sessions_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Current output:

[image]

### Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use `CardView` to get the shadow effect. Try the following layout as RecyclerView item, and see if it works.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="10dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_rounded_corner_black"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
      android:layout_width="13dp"
      android:layout_height="13dp"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:visibility="gone"
      app:civ_border_width="1dp"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_time"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_book"
      android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      tools:text="12 PM"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_book"
      android:text="2.1 mi."
      android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey"
      android:textSize="14sp"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_workout_Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_heavy"
    android:textColor="@color/color_black_1"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:text="HIIT Workout"/>


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_type_of_booking"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font_avenirltstd_book"
    android:text="One-Time Booking"
    android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Replace the tag `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` with the AndroidX CardView tag in case you're using AndroidX libraries. By using the `cardCornerRadius` tag, you don't need to give custom Background to your LinearLayout.

Also, don't forget to check if hardwareAccelerated = true in your Manifest file. It is already true if you're targeting API 14+. You won't see shadows if it's set to false.

Answer (score 2):

In case you came to check why elevation is not working on your `cardview` a mistake I have done is I had to change:

`android:elevation="8dp"`

with

`app:cardElevation="8dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion to you based on what I know:

1. Set your top-level RelativeLayout to have padding equal to the margins you've set on the relative layout that you want to show shadow;
2. Set `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the same RelativeLayout;
3. Remove the margin from the RelativeLayout that also has elevation set;
4. You may also need to set a non-transparent background color on the child layout that needs elevation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code to the Recycler view's item activity

```
android:outlineProvider="bounds"
android:elevation="3dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Android `CardView` is what you're looking for. Put your calendar and each element inside a card.

Change the card elevation for modifying the shadow size.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a cardview, for each elements must be inside cardview like that, example:

```
     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >

 <com.marcohc.robotocalendar.RobotoCalendarView
          android:id="@+id/robotoCalendarView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:elevation="10dp"
          android:visibility="visible"
          app:mcv_calendarMode="month"
          app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/CalendarDateTextAppearance"
          app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/CalendarHeaderTextAppearance"
          app:mcv_leftArrow="@drawable/mcv_action_previous"
          app:mcv_monthLabels="@null"
          app:mcv_rightArrow="@drawable/mcv_action_next"
          app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/color_red"
          app:mcv_selectionMode="single"
          app:mcv_showOtherDates="out_of_range"
          app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalendarWeekTextAppearance"/>


 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Best Regards